# Dompdf not working in live server (using Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I use `dompdf` to export some data on my website, in my local it works perfectly fine. but, after I push it into my live server but, it returns 404 not found.

This is my blade for exporting pdf

```
@if($post->lob)
    <span display="inline" style="text-transform: uppercase;">{{ $post->lob }} </span> - {{ $post->category->translate(app()->getLocale())->name }}
@else
    {{ $post->category->translate(app()->getLocale())->name }}
@endif
<h1 class="title">{{ $post->translate()->title }}</h1>

@if($post->translate()->image)
  <img src="{{ public_path('uploads/images/large/'.$post->translate()->image) }}" style="width:100%;">
@else
  <img src="{{ public_path('uploads/images/large/large-fifgroup.jpg') }}" style="width:100%;">

@endif

{!! $post->translate()->body !!}
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

For your information, i use Nginx for server

Comment: Can you share the error log? It's inside `storage/logs`.

Comment: Please share some code and if images are really necessary, embed them in the question

Comment: @HarunRRayhan okay wait a sec i'll check it

Comment: @ChristopheHubert i've write it on the question now. sorry, its a bit late

Comment: @HarunRRayhan strangely, i cannot find the error in storage.logs related to export dompdf

Comment: hi, did you get solution for this?